# Sending data from packetlistener service to UI

Tags: java, android

im in need of a solution abot how can i change UI from service variables,im listening for chat messages from service,i know how to turn messages into string, but i dont know how to send them into UI OR to another activity, here is my service:

```
 public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
this.connection = connection;
if (connection != null) {
  // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
  PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);

  connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
@Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
      Message message = (Message) packet;
      if (message.getBody() != null) {
        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", " Text Recieved " + message.getBody() + " from  
 " +  fromName);
        messages.add(fromName + ":");
        messages.add(message.getBody());
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",message.getBody());
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            setListAdapter();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }, filter);

}
}
```

and here is where that data belongs in main activity

```
 public void setListAdapter() {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
 R.layout.listitem, messages);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
          }
```

i have otto bus library in case, so i tried to use intent and otto just before mhandler.post but seems it totally stops the process... could you u guys help me here? thanks

here i did with mHandler.obtainMessage :

```
  messages.add(fromName + ":");
        messages.add(message.getBody());
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",message.getBody());
        mHandler.obtainMessage(1,message).sendToTarget();

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
    //        setListAdapter();

          }
        });
```

and in the activity :

```
private class getit extends Handler{

public void handleMessage(Message msg)
{
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          setListAdapter();
        }
      });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a private class inside my Activity that extends Handler.

With this line you can send a message:

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(int, message).sendToTarget();
```

The Handler class provides a callbackfunction where you can react on the message.

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // your code to show the message
}
```

That way you have the `Message` accessible at your Activity and can add it to your ListView.

Comment: may i ask what is int for ? i tried it, created a private class inside activity,got body from msg, and yet nothing :(

Comment: also should i put any thing in the sendtotarget?

Comment: You pass just an object, the int can be used to specify the type of the object if there could be more types than just one type `Message`

Comment: No that function doesn't need any parameters. When you tried it like this, where there any errors shown in the LogCat? Or what did you mean with "seems to stop"?

Comment: You don't need the mHandler.post nor the runnable in both the service and the activity. Just call your function setListAdapter

Comment: did as u said,still nothing, by the way i dont know what is the int argument for. 12 hours of trying and i end up with saving to file and reading from it, thanks any way mate, i accept your answer

Comment: I wrote it earlier. It's for specifying the type or the message. The parameter is called 'what' in the API. OK thanks :)